# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier with axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I am trying to use axios as following:

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.post("http://localhost:3000/test", {"prop1": "value"}, {headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}})
```

then the compiler complains:

```
/home/developer/Desktop/reason/interoperate/src/Ax.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import axios from 'axios';
                                                                     ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:246:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:298:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:670:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:744:10)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:238:19)
developer@monad:~/Desktop/reason/interoperate/src$ node Ax.js
/home/developer/Desktop/reason/interoperate/src/Ax.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import axios from 'axios';
```

Do I import wrong path?

Comment: which version of nodejs are you using? If I were you, i would try to use require syntax and not import

Comment: The node version is `v10.4.0`. With `var axios = require('axios');` it works. But I need with `import`.

Comment: Why do you need import? At the moment node 10.4.0 works with import as experimental feature and I guess this just include your own modules (with extension mjs) and node core modules (like fs for example). https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html If you need to use import then I guess you could use babel or some transpiler but nowadays require is the option to go until import start being fully functional

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Node.js doesn't fully support ES modules yet, which means you cannot use the `import` keyword. You can use it now with a source code transpiler like Babel and Webpack, but that will require a build step.

*Edit:* To be fair, Node.js 10.4.0 has an [experimental support for ES modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html), which is behind a flag: `--experimental-modules`. This will also require using the `.mjs` file extension for your JS files.

The feature is currently marked as **Stability: 1 - Experimental** - *Use of the feature is not recommended in production environments.*

Comment: It's not truth at all. NodeJS 10 is supporting it but at experimental feature yet

Answer (score 3):

I was also stuck here but I found the answer here :
https://github.com/nuxt/docs/issues/42

Since node.js still doesn't support import in official stable release, we should use require keyword. Something like this:
 const Axios=require('axios');

Of course, do remember to install axios module from npm.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it work with node 10.4.0 in next way:

```
// Create a file named index.mjs (the extension is the key)

import axios from 'axios';

console.log(axios);
```

Run it as:

```
node --experimental-modules index.mjs
```

But this feature is still experimental, should be avoided in production systems.